# Is it possible to tell which files the real-time protection feature of the Windows Antimalware Service has scanned recently?

Tags: windows, windows-defender

I frequently notice the Windows Antimalware Service taking a good chunk of CPU time, mostly when doing work. I do SW development, so I'm guessing there's a quite a bit of filesystem churn involved with files that don't really present a threat since they're either what I made, or libraries where compromising a developer workstation isn't really a major attack vector as far as I know.

I tried excluding my WSL installation and my projects folder, but I still get activity spikes. Is there a way to figure out what files were scanned during these so I can set up exclusions appropriately?

Comment: No. See [log files - Where are windows 10 defender offline scan logs/results? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/816870/where-are-windows-10-defender-offline-scan-logs-results)

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see which files are opened by that service while it's churning on.